# memory leak management Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am trying to learn about using instruments to find memory leaks in my app and I get a few of them. But I do not understand what is the problem if in the end object is released and free? What is more I can't find what function is responsible because it references some OS functions (start, `malloc_zone_malloc` etc.)  [image]

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer to the following question: [Information displayed by Allocations/leaks tools in Xcode Instruments appears incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682161/information-displayed-by-allocations-leaks-tools-in-xcode-instruments-appears-in)

Comment: I've read this. I have nothing to open in Xcode in this tree cause all of the functions are system's.

Comment: If the call tree view is empty after selecting the Hide System Libraries checkbox, update your question with that information.